# Next JS keeps showing old data sent by api endpoints

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am building a NextJS application with NextJS 13. I don't want to have any cache in the app because I always want to be sure to have up to date data.

Stack: NextJS 13, Prisma ORM, NeonDB

My `page.tsx` file contains the following to make sure no cache is applied:

```
export const revalidate = 0
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
```

All my endpoints have the following options:

```
{
  cache: 'no-store',
}
```

However, when I update a data, I then use

```
const toggleEndpoint = (isCollected: boolean) => async () => {
  await fetch('/api/expenses/recurrents', {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      type: 'toggleCollected',
      isCollected,
    }),
  })
  router.refresh()
}
```

Finally, I also tried updated my `vercel.json` file:

```
"headers": [
    {
      "source": "/(.*)",
      "headers": [
        {
          "key": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        },
        {
          "key": "Pragma",
          "value": "no-cache"
        },
        {
          "key": "Expires",
          "value": "0"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

But nothing seems to happen, I still have the old data displayed, when I check in database I have the updated data. Anyone knows what I can try ?

EDIT: I found a workaround, by adding the `request` parameter to my GET endpoint and using it, it seems to effectively call the endpoint and return up to date data.

```
export async function GET(request: Request) {
  console.log(request.url)
  const amountLeft = await prisma.amountOnAccount.findFirst({
    where: {
      userId: {
        equals: process.env.USER_ID,
      },
    },
  })

  return NextResponse.json(amountLeft ? amountLeft.amount : 0)
}
```

Comment: You need to consume the data, `const data = await fetch(...)`, but in your version, the data is ignored and then you simply refresh the route?

Comment: @windmaomao Yes I ignore the data returned, I do exactly like in the example https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/mutating

Answer (score 1):

Glad you figured it out by yourself,

Alternatively we can also use

```
    revalidatePath(request.url)
```

just before returning the response in API